# How do I test NHibernate's Restrictions.Not?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, nunit, xunit.net

I am trying to test my code. There is a need to test the functionality of a module which works with NHibernate's Criteria. For example here is one of my unit tests.

```
[Fact]
public void test_name()
{
  var criteria = ... // creates mock criteria
  MyModule.DoWork(criteria); // adds restrictions to criteria

  Assert.True(/* check if criteria.Add() was called
  and what arguments were passed */);
}
```

If the MyModule.DoWork() adds a Restrictions.Eq(), there is no problem, because it returns a SimpleExpression and I can check the expression.PropertyName and expression.Value. But if instead it adds Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq()) (which returns AbstractCriterion) there is no way to check the PropertyName and Value.

What do I do in such case? How to test against Restrictions.Not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example test `ToString()` result of your `AbstractCriterion` ( which should be [NotExpression](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/NotExpression.cs) with a nested private `_criterion`)

Anyway, I don't see it as a good idea. I may be off-topic here, but I would rather test the behavior of the result than its structure, or the result of `ToString()`. The main point being (IMHO) what the code does, more than its conformance to your knowledge of the target data-structure.

I guess it would be better to setup an in-memory database ( SqlLite comes to mind ) and test applying your restrictions on a test set. And it seems similar to (part of) the way NH is tested https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Test/Criteria/CriteriaQueryTest.cs